# iptables - get net access with nat and one public IPv4

Tags: iptables, nat

I have one public IPV4 address, a host and one virtual machine (IP 192.168.100.10)
With iptables on the host side I succeeded in redirecting only port 22(ssh) toward the host with the help of the nat table.

Nat table :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.10
```

Filter table :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I would like to be still able to access the web from the host and the virtual machine.

I tried to add on the Filter tab :

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
```

But still impossible to get web access from the host. By the way PING from the host to an external IP is working perfectly.

NAT table :

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             to:192.168.100.10

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

FILTER table :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination                     
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web access from host doesn't work because your firewall INPUT filter drops (almost) all incoming packets, including those which are replies to packets sent from the host. Only icmp and tcp 22 packets match ACCEPT rules and get accepted, therefore only ping and ssh work, but nothing else.

Say, you access DNS, your host sends packet to outside from some port to udp 53, DNS server replies with ports and addresses reversed. A reply packet is incoming into your host: a udp packet from DNS server with source port 53, but the first rule in the filter INPUT which matches it is the DROP rule.

There is a connection tracker in Linux which inspects all packets entering into host (except those set as NOTRACK in the raw table), and sets some flags if it determines the packet belongs or relates to some known connection (created by a packet you ACCEPTed before with some other rule of default policy, like your filter OUTPUT chain). You can check some of these flags in the INPUT filter chain. Do that before DROP action:

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

This rule uses conntrack flags to permit replies to packets originated on the local system.

To access outside world from the virtual machine, you need to add another translation rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.10 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

this is a kind of SNAT rule, but it says "translate to whatever address output interface has", instead of specifying that address in the rule.

Beware packets going from external world to virtual machine and vice versa all go through filter FORWARD chain, but not through filter INPUT or filter OUTPUT. If you are ever going to drop something in the FORWARD chain to limit what virtual machine could access and who could access it, you might want to also add similar conntrack rule into the beginning of filter FORWARD chain, to enable replies of established connections to reach their destinations, like you've done for the host itself in the filter INPUT chain.

Your ACCEPT rules in the OUTPUT chain in this case do nothing. You don't DROP or REJECT anything in the OUTPUT filter, your default policy for the OUTPUT is ACCEPT. You can empty (flush) filter OUTPUT chain and it would still work.

Comment: Thank you, it's working as expected now ! Very well explained!